# What does "send her/his fleeing for" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've come across with the sentence below:

> Hitler's dream of empire had yet to crumble and send her fleeing for
>   the shadows

.

I searched in online dictionaries but I didn't find any explanation for it.

So, could you tell me please what it means?

The fuller text is:

> She fired six times shots on the shore of the Lake Rusalka, not
>   attempting to hide what she did. Why would she? Hitler's dream of
>   empire had yet to crumble and **send her fleeing for the shadows**... They called her... The Huntress. She was the young mistress of an SS officer in German-occupied Poland.

*The Huntress* by Kate Quinn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I **send you fleeing** I do something that causes you to flee.

> The cartel moved into the city and sent the local drug kingpins fleeing.

In your example, the syntax is like this:

> ... had yet to ... send her fleeing

That is, "had yet to" governs **crumble** *and* **send**.

> The driver of the car had yet to **commit** an infraction and **give** the police officer probable cause to stop and search the car.

The syntax is somewhat elliptical:

> The driver of the car had yet to **commit** an infraction and [thereby] **give** the police officer probable cause to stop and search the car.

The dream of empire had not crumbled yet [which it would eventually do] and sent her fleeing.

We can avoid the ellipsis by saying it so:

> Hitler's dream of empire had not yet crumbled **to** send her fleeing for the shadows...
>
> The cartel had not yet arrived in the city **to** send the local drug kingpins fleeing.

The infinitive clause complement in that pattern is a *result* not an *intention* or *purpose*.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the verb 'send' with an object and a word or phrase:

I sent her away.
I sent him to London.
The weather sent me into the house.
I sent the stone flying through the window.

The crumbling of Hitler's empire sent her fleeing (running away from danger) into the shadows (to a hiding place or series of them).

[Send](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/send)

[Flee](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flee)